# XAMPP for windows vista: folder inside htdocs

Tags: php, apache, xampp, directory

I have my xampp instalation up and running. 
I have a php file with just

```
<?php
echo"Hello World";
?>
```

This I can see in my browser when I place it inside C:\xampp\htdocs

But if I place it inside C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder  I get an error 500 server not found.

What's wrong with putting my file inside myfolder? Is that because of Vista? Any advice?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? A 500, a 404 or something else? What is your web root?

Comment: you should create your folder inside the htdocs instead of htdocs inside your folder try C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder..

Comment: sorry it was a lapse, I meant C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder

Comment: Do you access it going to `http://localhost/myfolder`, righ?

Comment: have you give correct url into browser?? http://localhost/myfolder/filename.php
???

Comment: yes, I've tried, but error 500 again

Comment: yes, I've copied the name of the folder and pasted it just in case and I've made sure that filename.php is inside (and that is the same file that was working outside the folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I'd try restarting Xampp services via the Xampp Control Panel (especially Apache). If the problem is still there check xampp\apache\logs for errors. Depending on how familiar you are with Xampp I'd check to make sure the Apache service is running (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services), restart it manually and test again.

I'm pretty sure I've had a similar issue to this in the past with Xampp when my computer crashed while Apache was running, which I think I only managed to solve by reinstalling Xampp though. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You're placing it in the wrong directory.

> C:\xampp\myfolder\htdocs

If you want to access the file you should put it under the `htdocs` directory.
Do this instead

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\

Comment: @user995247 Try doing a fresh install. or just use WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the access rights of the folder? Maybe it is not accessable via localhost. Windows 6+ is very strict related to accessing directorys. If you can't find it then set the UAC to a lower lewer to test it, if you think it's safe enough.